# Растянуть див по высоте содержимого

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Есть сайт на Wordpress. Установил на него слайдер (не плагином). Слева кнопки переключения, справа слайды. Контент каждого слайда отличается по высоте, нужно сделать так, что бы всё, что находиться ниже самого слайдера автоматически подстраивалось по высоте (между слайдером и остальными блоками на странице не было большого промежутка), в зависимости от активного слайда. Помогите пожалуйста, ниже приведу код:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="slidorion">
<div id="slider">
<div class="slider-image" rel="section1" style="opacity: 1; z-index: 1;">контент</div>
<div class="slider-image" rel="section2" style="opacity: 0;">контент</div>
<div class="slider-image" rel="section3" style="opacity: 0;">контент</div>
</div>      
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#header {
width: 300px;
height: 120px;
margin: 20px auto;}

#slidorion {
width: 1140px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
margin-left: -415px;}

#slider{
width: 751px;
height: 845px;
position: relative;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;}

.slider-image {
position: absolute;}
```

Comment: ответ очевидный - не указывайте высоту вообще

Comment: @МаксимЛенский но тогда слайды вообще не отображаются

Comment: у вас размер изображений ставится от контейнера ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ну там есть и изображение и ссылки и текст. Если в консоле разработчика навожу на `<div class="slider-image" rel="section2" style="opacity: 0;">контент</div>`, то мне подсвечивает и ширину и высоту. Или вы про другое?

Comment: ну вот смотрите - есть родительский блок а внутри картинка , в этом случае обычно размер ставят для родительского блока а img ставится width height 100% т.е картинка займёт  100% по горизонтали и вертикали или бывает по другому - когда размер указывают именно картинке

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Мне нужно что бы родительские блоки плавали по высоте, в зависимости от того сколько контента в том или ином слайдере.

Comment: читайте самый первый мой комментарий